# How to get a youtube playlist thumbnail?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is there a way to get youtube playlist thumbnail like how you can get a thumbnail of a video, explained here: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

Answer (score 13):

With the YouTube API v3, you can get the playlist thumbnail using their `v3/playlists` endpoint and drilling down to `items.snippet.thumbnails.high.url`

For the following playlist:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL50C17441DA8A565D

YouTube's API explorer has a playlist endpoint:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

This is the API call:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id=PL50C17441DA8A565D&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

And here is the response:

```
    {
     "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#playlist",
       "id": "PL50C17441DA8A565D",
       "snippet": {
        "title": "Jay Chou Playlist",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kGbDymJ75PU/default.jpg",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kGbDymJ75PU/mqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 320,
          "height": 180
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kGbDymJ75PU/hqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 480,
          "height": 360
         }
        },
        "channelTitle": "it23"
       }
      }
     ]
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me.  Similar to the other post regarding playlist items but I just changed the API call.  Hope it helps.

//get playlist itmes

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=< YOUR API KEY >&part=snippet&playlistId="<Put your playlist id here>");
```

//decode response from youtube

```
$json = json_decode($data);
```

//if you want to see the full response use print_r($json);

//each items in the response corresponds to a video in the playlist so lets get the first video (items[0]) get its snippet and corresponding thumbnails and we will take the url for the default size. If you want the second video use items [1] etc.

```
$video_thumbnail = $json->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;
```

//set the videos alt tag as the snippet description

```
$video_alt = $json->items[0]->snippet->description;
```

//echo the image url into an image tag

```
echo '<img src="'. $video_thumbnail .'" alt="'. $video_alt .'" />';
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no API for this purpose. Here is a workaround I can think of.

1) What youtube playlist thumbnail is? Played around with my account and seems the rule is as below:

```
if playlist has 5+ videos
  thumbnail = first 5 video images
else if playlist has 1+ videos
  thumbnail = all video images
else shows this list is empty
```

2) Then you can use the same way to get video thumbnails.

3) combine the images either on the client side (some CSS) or server side

Comment: well I understand that, but say I have a playlist id, how do I get the first video's id so that I can pull the tumbnail of the 1st video?
I just want to show a relevan thumbnail and it doesn't matter for me if it is a 3rd or 1st one.

Comment: Below API returns the videos for a given playlist(2C441924AEB5811E): http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/2C441924AEB5811E. You can get the video thumbnail from any entry.