# Youtube Player Integration with Thumbnail in Android App

Tags: android, youtube

Hi i follow tutorial on CodingwithMitch about using Youtube API in android. It is a good tutorial to start. 
Everything is running perfectly however when the player is idle the screen is just blank instead of showing the video thumbnail/preview.
[screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBBem.jpg)

I would like to make the idle screen shows vid thumbnail so i know what video will be played.

The code in MyActivity.xml is below:

```
<view                    class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView"
                android:id="@+id/youtubePlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
```

YouTube Config code:

```
public class YouTubeConfig {public YouTubeConfig() {} private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyXXXXXX";public static String getApiKey(){
return API_KEY;}}
```

And in my MainActivity.java

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
YouTubePlayerView mYoutubePlayerView;
Button btnPlay;
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //PlayYouTube
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    mYoutubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);
    mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationSuccess: Done Initialising.");
            youTubePlayer.loadPlaylist("PLZRTg9sNaMaFnh04-HODVcYRlFtKO8rsS");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationSuccess: Fail to Initialize.");
        }
    };
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Initializing Youtube Player.");
            mYoutubePlayerView.initialize(YouTubeConfig.getApiKey(), mOnInitializedListener);
        }
    });
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the thumbnail for the youtube video that you want its preview to display.
[Get a thumbnail from youtube video](https://coderwall.com/p/nihgwq/get-a-thumbnail-from-a-youtube-video)

Comment: Yes i knew that, but how exactly to implement/integrate YouTube thumbnail API to the project?

Comment: @vegatroz I don't get what you really mean but in my project I did something like this: `String img_url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + result.getKey() + "/0.jpg";
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(img_url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .into(thumbnailImageView); `

Comment: Thanks Regent, however i use video playlist in my codes, so how can i show the thumbnail of every video in the playlist automatically?

Comment: @vegatroz How about if you go through this link?  It really help me get my own done some time back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628760/how-to-get-a-youtube-playlist-thumbnail